# Ubuntu performance monitor tools like PerfMon

Tags: performance, ubuntu, performance-testing, ubuntu-14.04, performancecounter

I am looking for a tool in Ubuntu like PerfMon.exe, what I need to have a report that report the CPU Usage , memory Usage per PID, and the output would be minimum, maximum and average between a period of time like I click start and stop testing.

edit1: 
I dont need tools like top,htop ... etc, I need a tool to monitor my load testing results, simple software that allow me to choose my PIDs, click start, then do my tests, then click stop, and get average-min-max CPU and memory usage

Comment: check system monitor utility in linux/ubuntu. If you are comfortable with terminal/command line then go for sar.

Comment: I dont need something for real time monitoring, , I need a simpler software, something like PerfMon.exe , just choose my PIDs, click start, do a load test, click stop get a report for min, max, average CPU and memory consumed.

Comment: Above mentioned utilities are simplest to use than others. I think you are windows guy (likes GUI). System monitor is present which will give you same like perfmon. For collecting data for specific duration read man sar.

Comment: thanks a lot, the closest thing to my requirments is the following command:
pidstat -r -u -p <pid> -I 3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

thanks to Nachiket Kate
, the closest thing to my requirments is the following command: pidstat -r -u -p  -I 3

Comment: Glad I could help. In unix environment plenty of command line utilities for all purposes are available and are very easy to use and very fast in terms of performance than a GUI.

Answer (score 1):

Linux, and unix in general has a set of tools collectively known as 'process accounting'.  These let you show CPU usage, memory usage and other metrics per process.

Check that you have the [acct](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=acct) package installed.  A HOWTO for using it can be found [here.](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Process-Accounting/)

Note that these tools don't have an interactive GUI out of the box but they do have tools for viewing the logs.

Also [top(1)](http://linux.die.net/man/1/top) lets you show process activity in realtime.

Comment: many thanks, I need a simpler software, something like PerfMon.exe , just choose my PIDs, click start, do a load test, click stop get a report for min, max, average CPU and memory consumed.